how to read directly into a std::vector?
I want to read bytes directly into a std::vector.  I think I want do something like this, where read() is the standard Unix/Linux/Posix syscall, and where n is some number of bytes I want to read:
std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
buf.reserve(n);
size_t r = read(fd, &buf[0], n);

The problem here is of course that after doing the read, I know (in variable r) how many bytes were read into the vector, but the vector itself does not.  Somehow I'd have to tell the vector how big it is now, after which size() would return the right size.
But I have no idea how to do this.  Is there a way?  It seems I'd need a setsize mutator, but I can understand why that doesn't exist.  There's resize(), but it'd overwrite the just-read data with a default value, I think.
I know about the form involving std::istreambuf_iterator<char> as discussed in this question, but (a) I don't have such an iterator and (b) I want to do this on an already-existing vector (i.e. not just at construction time).

reserve gets storage, but isn't allowed to use it yet. The size of the vector is still zero.  You want resize here. You take a bit of a hit zeroing all those bits, but you can't get around that with a vector without getting weird and illegal (probably. Don't know legal ways).

There's ways to avoid the penalty of zeroing during resize, but they're generally not worth the effort. Just use resize

@user4581301 Aha!  Use resize before the read, not after it.  Got it.  Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

C++23 added resize_and_overwrite for std::basic_string, but not for std::vector.

Worrying about the performance of value-initialization when setting the initial vector size is kinda pointless, because most I/O routines are at least one or two orders of magnitude slower than that. I'd consider that to be a micro-optimization.

and if the scenario involves quickly repeated multiple read operations (e.g. reading from stream?) with small amount of data per operation, using pre-allocated buffers would be preferable than allocating for each operation.

The linked answer is what you are looking for, it has the .assign() example for the existing vector.

There are a couple of problems with your approach. To begin with, you are not allowed to access the vector's data beyond its actual size, even if it has capacity.
A technical reason for this is that the data at unused locations has not yet been constructed. But more specifically, it's because this usage rule is described by the standard (std::vector<T,Allocator>::operator[]):

Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

Because buf begins with a size of zero, it's therefore undefined behavior to access buf[0] at all. If you were to use buf.at(0), an exception would be thrown.
Additionally, you are using the wrong data type to store the return value from read. That function returns a ssize_t, not a size_t.
To achieve what you want, you need something like the following:
std::vector<uint8_t> buf(n);
ssize_t r = read(fd, buf.data(), n);
if (r > 0) {
    buf.resize(r);
} else {
    buf.clear();
}

This constructs a new vector with n elements, which are initially value-initialized. It then attempts to read data into this, and resizes the vector with the actual number of items read. On error, the vector is cleared
Performance note: Although the initialization of the vector prior to reading will result in redundancy (memory written twice), it's worth noting that a call to read is generally orders of magnitude less performant than initializing memory, because you're reading from a file handle. So it's not really worth worrying about, even in the best case where that file handle is a data pipe.
Note that I use buf.data() instead of &buf[0] to access the vector's internal data. I think this has clearer semantics.

Only std::vector's requirement make this UB. syd::uint8_t has vacuous initialisation so its ok to write to storage without first placing an object there, the write starts the lifetime of an object there. The problem is strictly because std::vector says you can't do this so it can assume you won't.

I agree with you about .data(); I meant to acknowledge that in the question.
